# Is pthread_kill async signal safe on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals

OpenGroup Unix spec [claims](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03) `pthread_kill()` to be async-signal-safe. But Linux [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) doesn't list this function in related section.

So, is it safe to call `pthread_kill` in signal handler on Linux? I know it is implemented using `tgkill()` (which is safe... but this doesn't automatically makes `pthread_kill()` safe too).

Some background:

- using `O_ASYNC/F_SETOWN_EX/F_SETSIG` to direct SIGRTMIN signals to specific thread on I/O readiness...
- unfortunately when real-time signal queue is full, Linux reverts to delivering SIGIO to entire process...
- to rectify this SIGIO handler is installed which forwards that signal back to designated thread (which blocks SIGIO and uses `sigwaitinfo()` in signals processing loop)

**Edit:** Signal processing thread treats received SIGIO as "we got activity, but don't know where -- check every file descriptor". Not ideal, but better than missing the signal completely.

**Edit 2:** Had to update the design a bit (for some unfathomable reason I thought SIGIO is a real-time signal).

Comment: The first link you posted _does_ list `pthread_kill` in the _async-signal-safe_ section directly. But, I'd pull the source to `glibc`. A comment in `pthread_kill` says the opposite of the doc. _One comment: The PID field in the TCB can temporarily be changed (in fork).  But this must not affect this code here.  Since this function would have to be called while the thread is executing fork, it would have to happen in a signal handler.  But this is no allowed, pthread_kill is not guaranteed to be async-safe._

Comment: What type of file descriptors are these?  If they are not files on disk, how about using `poll()` like everybody else does?

Comment: @JohnZwinck OP had a prior question [since deleted] that was talking about `SIGIO` usage. For some [unspecified] reason, he couldn't block the signal in all threads except the one. I suggested then that he replace all `sigwaitinfo` with `poll`. I wasn't going to mention it again [lest I be annoying], but since you've suggested it I will restate that the `poll` method is faster, simpler, and doesn't overflow the R/T sigqueue [which is no longer needed].

Comment: I know poll/etc is better, but I am working (bugfixing) with old, large and poorly written code (that uses signals for I/O). Converting it to better mechanisms is not practical (at this moment). I've tracked down most bugs and rewrote signal-related portion of it. It seem to be working but I need final piece -- ability to post a signal to another thread from a signal handler. If pthread_kill() isn't safe -- it hurts... I'd appreciate a bit of help in this case

Comment: @CraigEstey ... to be precise I can block signals in multiple threads, but not all of them.

Comment: Strange... This [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) lists `pthread_kill` as safe. But man page on my system (CentOS 7) doesn't.

Comment: CentOS uses `glibc`. To work around, at init from the "I/O thread" do: `glob_iotid = gettid()`. Then, in the signal handler, do `tgkill(...,glob_iotid,sig)`. This gets around ambiguity with `pthread_kill`

Comment: The CentOS/Fedora `man signal-safety` lists `pthread_kill` as safe. In the `glibc` source, it is talking about doing a `fork`. So, if you're not doing a `fork`, my take on the actual code itself is that it works despite the comment.

Comment: I think you should post some real source code and present the full problem rather than just snippets. You've been saying it's too hard to change the code base [to `poll`] but I'd like to see all the signal related code as I could probably replace it in a matter of days [I have 45+ years experience and do such things all the time when needed]. Why does `s/sigwaitinfo/poll/` not work? Are the threads using (non-SIGIO) signals to communicate rather than (e.g.) SysV IPC? If not here, what about posting the code to Code Review?

Comment: @CraigEstey wow... 45 years is impressive, but my 22 should be adequate for the task. Main reason to avoid changing stuff dramatically is convoluted crappy code and the fact that if I wanted to do it right -- I would have replaced entire communication layer.

Comment: Well, I guess that settles it -- looks like `pthread_kill()` is safe. My man is just too old -- it doesn't even have an entry for "signal-safety" nor does it list `tgkill()` as safe. Thank you, @CraigEstey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing Craig Estey's answers here (thanks, dude!):

In all (recent enough) man pages `pthread_kill` is listed as async-signal-safe. There is a comment in glibc sources which claims it isn't safe in the presence of `fork()`, so if you feel paranoid you could use `tgkill(getpid(), <thread-id>, <signal-id>)`.

So, yeah -- both `pthread_kill` and `tgkill` should be ok.

On my CentOS 7 `man` doesn't list any of them as safe, but it is likely due to the fact of it being too old.